# How to use ARRAY of INET in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a user model with array of ips field in my flask application. I want to use postgresql array of inet type:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY, INET, Integer, Unicode, Column
db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = Column(Unicode(15))
    password = Column(Unicode(34))
    name = Column(Unicode(100))
    permitted_ips = Column(ARRAY(INET))
```

But when i make query i get bad answer:

```
user = User.query.get(84)
print user.permitted_ips
#['{', '1', '7', '2', '.', '2', '0', '.', '2', '5', '.', '2', ',', '1', '7', '2', '.', '2', '0', '.', '2', '5', '.', '3', '}']
```

instead of ['172.20.25.2', '172.20.25.3']. Current version of sqlalchemy is 0.9.10. I tried the latest one but result was the same. Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Arrays are not parsed automatically so you need to create a [generic type caster](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.new_array_type) with psycopg2 library.

```
# needed imports
from psycopg2 import STRING
from psycopg2.extensions import register_type, new_array_type
```

Registering the array type, it will be done one time.

```
# to see the oid of inet. As pointed out by @univerio the oid should never             
# change, so you don't need to fetch it every time your app starts.
tp = db.engine.execute("select typarray from pg_type where typname = 'inet'")
print(tp.fetchone())
# (1041,)

# registering the array type
register_type(new_array_type((1041,), 'INET[]', STRING))
```

Now you can fetch the array and it will be parsed properly.

```
# fetch data
ips = db.engine.execute("select permitted_ips from users where id = 1")
print(ips.fetchone()[0])
# ['172.20.25.2', '172.20.25.3'].
```

Comment: It is definitely cleaner to register the array type as opposed to ad hoc parsing the "wrong" string.

Comment: You mean safer? I'm not an expert, can you explain please?

Comment: No, it's cleaner. If you have to do this ad hoc conversion *everywhere* you need to access user.permitted_ips, wouldn't it be nice to have it done automatically before you even set it on the object? Same reason why it doesn't just give you integers as strings and ask you to do `int(user.id)` every time.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. When I said that's cleaner its because I proposed to use SQL instead of ORM itself and I think that was messy... Anyway, maybe there's a way to do that with sqlalchemy, I will do my research, thaks again!

Comment: I see. The oid of the builtin types should not ever change, so you don't have to fetch that from PostgreSQL every time your app starts up.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it works for select but update raises an error: **sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "permitted_ips" is of type inet[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: UPDATE passwd SET permitted_ips=ARRAY['172.20.25.2'] WHERE p...**